# Lambda function with filter

Tags: python

Only include products that are non-discontinued (discontinued=0) with unit_price greater than 15.0 in the new list.
How I can solve this? How can I select and use `discontinued=0` with unit_price and put it into the code?

```
print (list(filter(lambda x: x=0,>15,products)))
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine products are either objects of a certain `Product` class, or are dicts, if that's the case, you can use:

#### For objects of a certain class (having `discontinued` and `unit_price` attributes):

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.discontinued == 0 and x.unit_price > 15, products)))
```

#### For dicts (having `discontinued` and `unit_price` keys):

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x['discontinued'] == 0 and x['unit_price'] > 15, products)))
```